# Causes for negative port resistance of passive device (or obtaining |S11|>0 from measurements)

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, impedance-matching, circuit-theory, s-parameters

Suppose you have two reciprocal (passive) devices, A and B, both described with S-parameters \$S_a\$ and \$S_b\$. With a VNA, you measure \$S_a\$ and \$S_{\rm tot}\$ (S-parameters of AB, both devices cascaded).

From circuit theory, we can convert both to its T-parameters, \$T_{\rm tot}\$ and \$T_a\$. Now we know that $$T_{\rm tot}=T_a T_b\,.$$

So we can obtain

$$
T_b = T_a^{-1} T_{\rm tot} ,
$$

and convert this to \$S_b\$.

There is just one problem: For my measurements, \$|S_{b,11}| \gt 1\$ or, in other words, the real part of the input port impedance of B (its *resistance*!) is less than zero.

This is clearly wrong because the devices are passive. How can this happen? Which sanity checks can be invoked to see where things/intermediate results are wrong (maybe which measurement point is off)? Intuitively, under which condition can this happen?

---

**Additional Info:** The measured results at 915MHz are:

$$
S_a = \begin{bmatrix}
  -0.0376-i0.2195 &  0.0949-i0.7257 \\
   0.0949-i0.7257 & -0.2423-i0.1649 \\
\end{bmatrix} .
$$

\$S_a\$ is is a signal path on a PCB which includes (passing) RF switches, a discrete delay line and ac coupling caps. Parameters were measured using the method from https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/780284 with an Agilent VNA at -30dBm but large amount of averaging. The magnitues (return loss and insertion loss) make sense to me and are on the order of what I expect from simulations.

\$S_b\$ is actually a one-port (just a termination impedance), hence I only care about \$S_{b,11}\$. When I measure \$S_{\rm tot}\$, I can still treat it as two-port, just with \$S_{12}=S_{22}=0\$ and \$S_{21}\$ arbitrary. My measurements for \$S_{\rm tot}\$ are:

$$
S_{\rm tot} =  \begin{bmatrix}
  -0.2285+i0.2936 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} .
$$

Using this measured data and the approach from above, I obtain:

$$
S_{b,11} = −0.2194−i1.1959 .
$$

Choosing a characteristic impedance \$Z_0=50\Omega\$, this corresponds to a *negative* input impedance: \$Z_{\rm b,in} = -8.2055-i40.997\Omega\$ (any \$Z_0\$ will result in a negative input impedance!). This is unphysical (it could only be generated by an active element). For comparison, the output impedance of block A is \$Z_{\rm a,out}=29.0993-i10.4982\Omega\$. As such, it is not possible to find an L-match to match the impedance between the two blocks.

Comment: First sanity check: If you compute (Ta^-1)*Ta, what do you get?

Comment: What is your actual device, andwhat is the intermediate device? Do you get this  "funny" result at all frequencies or only at certain frequencies? How noisy are your measurements?

Comment: @BrianDrummond \$T_a^{-1} T_a\$ gives me the identity matrix. The eigenvalues of \$I-S_a^H S_a\$ are real-valued, positive and smaller than 1 in magnitude.

Comment: So, first sanity check passed. And this isn't my field so good luck.

Comment: @ThePhoton The actual devices are PCBs with only passive components. The measurements are not too noisy I think (I enabled significant averaging on the VNA). I haven't tried multiple frequencies yet. For debugging, I'd just be curious what could cause such a behavior. I tried to "unroll" the algebra based on the \$|S_{b,11}|>1\$ to see what could be the conditions on \$S_a\$ or \$S_{\rm tot}\$ for this to happen. But the math just gets too messy for an insight.

Comment: If you can share the actual circuits and frequencies it would help. For example, if \$|S_{21}^a|\$ is very small at the frequency you tested, then you might lose your measurement of \$S_{11}^b\$ in the measurement noise. But I can't tell if that's a likely explanation without knowing more about your actual circuit(s)

Comment: @ThePhoton I have added all details incl. my measured values. Unfortunately \$S_{21}^a\$ is not very small. To me, the results look fairly meaningful and are on the order I expect them from simulations.

Comment: I calculated \$S_{11}^b\$ direct from the s-parameters (without transforming to T parameters) and got \$-0.2194-1.1959j\$. Does this agree with your calculation?

Comment: @ThePhoton Indeed, this is what I get! (I did not know there is a short-cut without T-parameters). This corresponds to Z=-8.2055-j40.997 Ohm at Z0=50 Ohm. In contrast, Sb22=-0.2423 - 0.1649i (or Z=29.0993 -10.4982i Ohm @50Ohm). Of course, it's not possible to build a proper L-match (which is my ultimate goal)

Comment: Have you calibrated the measurement setup correctly? If you somehow calibrate with more attenuation than your DUT causes that will result in seemingly "amplified" signal. That can happen for example if you use adapters in calibration but not in the actual measurement.

Comment: Yes, I calibrated everything up to the first port of "device A".

Comment: What switching chip (or other termination method) did you use to measure the network A characteristics? Surely you don't have access to the one built at Sandia 20 years ago?

Comment: @ThePhoton I used the method, not the hardware. In particular, I made three measurements with a precision 50-Ohm resistor, a short and an open. (As I said, in terms of RL and IL the results match simulation)

Comment: Did you assume the standards were perfect (i.e. the match had \$\Gamma=0\$, the open had \$\Gamma=1\$, and the short had \$\Gamma=-1\$, or did you measure the response of each standard? Were the standards geometrically similar to each other?

Comment: PIctures of the actual physical structures you're testing would also be helpful, if you're free to share them.